# Use moderncv casual icons in moderncv classic layout

Tags: moderncv

I am rewriting my CV in LaTeX using `moderncv` and prefer the look of the phone/social icons from the `casual` style but the layout of the `classic` style. How do I use the `casual` icons in the `classic` style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style `casual` of class `moderncv` uses the command `\moderncvicons{awesome}` to load the symbols you prefer with font `fontawesome`, style `classic` you prefer uses command `\moderncvicons{marvosym}`.

So simply add command `\moderncvicons{awesome}` in your preamble **after** calling style `classic`!

See the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\moderncvicons{awesome} % <============== to get symbols of style casual
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-golden-upright}%
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\end{document}
```

and its result

[image: resulting pdf with font awesome]